# ng mock e2e Unexpected Request

Tags: angularjs, mocking, ui-testing, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using the ngMockE2E to mock the httpBackend while developing the UI in Angular JS. The App runs on a Grizzly-Server with a backend which is provided by a virtual machine. Now when I go on the Website the Console logs the Error:

Unexpected request: GET /api/info

No more request expected

In my case I only want to mock the data of one database. Additional to that I want to turn the mock ON/OFF on the fly via a button. This was working until the Error comes up.
For that case I've written the following:

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST(function (url) {
        if (!mockup) {
            return false;
        }
        var target_url = (someUrl);
        return target_url === url;
    }).respond(function (method, url, data) {
        return [200, [someData], {}, 'mockupData'];
    }
);
```

Additional to that I've added the following to pass all the other requests:

```
// pass the rest of the queries
$httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
$httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();
$httpBackend.whenPUT(/.*/).passThrough();
$httpBackend.whenDELETE(/.*/).passThrough();
```

Comment: Are you using directly from file:// or you have a server? if you use from file, try to install any small http server, like node http server. Because one time I has a similar problem with get and mock using file://

Comment: it runs on a server. So I think my problem is a little bit different. But thank you for comment.

I extended my question with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for all of you who face the same problem. I found a workaround for the issue. But I'm sure there should be another better solution. 
For that I used an Interceptor which is also provided by angular. [Here the api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

So I wrote this:

```
app.factory('httpInterceptor', function () {
        return {
            'response': function (response) {
                // therefore you can enable the mockup with a switch or a button
                if (!mockup) {
                    return response;
                }
                try {
                    // in the config object is the requested url
                    if (response.config.url !== someUrl) {
                        // don't intercept; return response unchanged
                        return response;
                    }
                    // found an url which should be mocked
                    // generate or modify the data
                    var generatedData = generateSomeData();
                    response.data.push(generatedData)
                    return response;
                } catch (TypeError) {
                    // don't intercept
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);
```